# Converting NSTextView formatted text to NSData (and back)

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nstextview, nsattributedstring, nstextstorage

How should I convert the contents of an `NSTextView` to `NSData`, and then convert it back and display it, on Mac OS X?

I can convert the text without formatting by using `textView.textStorage.string` (where textView is the `NSTextView` object). However, I want to save the text formatting as well.

In fact I have implemented an approach that works, but I'm not sure it is guaranteed to always work.  I encode the `NSTextStorage` object itself and write it, and then read it back as an `NSAttributedString`.  (`NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSAttributedString`.)  I do this because I cannot directly set `textStorage` for the `NSTextView`, but I can set its attributed string.

Here is my code to convert it (the result is in `data`):

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];          
[archiver encodeObject:textView.textStorage forKey:@"attrs"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
```

To read it back:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSAttributedString* theAttrString = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"attrs"];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

and to display it:

```
[textView.textStorage setAttributedString:theAttrString];
```

Is this approach guaranteed to work, given that I encode an `NSTextStorage` object and read it back interpreting it as an `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: I don't see why not. This seems like a perfectly valid serialization approach. However, the question, "Is this a good approach?" is a little subjective, so it may not be the *best* question to ask here.

Comment: Thanks - I have edited the final question to make it less subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will work. `NSTextStorage` will use the `NSCoding` implementation of `NSAttributedString`, so when you encode the data, you'll actually be encoding an `NSAttributedString`. This means that you will read the data back as an immutable object, even though you wrote a mutable object.

Obviously, that's fine if you use the `setAttributedString:` method, so you'll use the encoded immutable data to update the mutable state. This should work flawlessly, as long as your serialization/deserialization code is correct.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the explanation. But could NSTextStorage define its own implementation of NSCoding that breaks this, now or in the future?

Comment: @Radpole No, even if `NSTextStorage` defined its own implementation (which it currently doesn't, according to the Apple documentation), since the resulting class still extends `NSAttributedString`, all the methods would still work as normal. Sleep easy.